# JEDI JCL Compress in memory/direct to disk?

Tags: delphi, stream, zip, jedi, jedi-code-library

I have used `TZIPForge` for a long time now. Now I would like to change to JEDI JCL Compress.

With `TZIPForge` I can decide whether it compressed fully in memory or whether it writes to disk directly while compressing.

JEDI JCL seems to compress fully in memory which can cause problems with very big files. How is it possible to write directly to disk instead?

Comment: You haven't given us any code to work with, and you've asked two questions. Pick one question. Ask it alone. Include a small [mcve] that illustrates your point.

Comment: There isn't any code so I can not give any. So Question 1 is more important for me. I don't need a complete code example or something like this. I just would like to know how to write to disk directly (IF possible with JCL).

Comment: How can there be no code? You can compress a file without any code? How?

Comment: You missunderstood me. I edited my question above.

Comment: Basically this falls then under the "select me a library" type of questions that seem not fit to SO format of short precise answers. See FAQ.  "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow...."

Comment: I never asked about another library.

Comment: Additionally - `cArchive := cFormat.Create('C:\test.7z');` - that is not ZIP file, it is VERY different format. If you want to compare 7z wrappers - those would be quite a different than ZIP implementations. I think i remember two other 7z wrappers Henri Gourvest's progdidy (now dead) and Delphi Inspirations one. Maybe they are "closer to the bone", to the low-level 7z API.

Comment: Maybe I wrote in my test code 7z. But if 7z, zip, gzip doesn't matter because JCL Compression compresses everything in memory first which is not good.

Comment: I didn't misunderstand what was written. I asked you not to ask more than one question. Please stop doing that. Please edit the question.  You destroyed my edit.

Comment: How can you use memory stream? For what? Can write directly to disk? Well, how does a memory stream fit into this. I think you need to work harder at asking your questions.

Comment: Basically he would have to "Use the source, Luke". `TStream` is an abstract interface, that does not require it content existing. It might be generated on demand (like in random numbers, prime numbers, or disk files read from disk to memory on demand). So as long at the compressing library can operate on `TStream` it does not matter if it works "in memory" or not - one can always wrap his data into on-demand-generating proxy streams. However here we have a wrapper that might follow the pattern or go lazy way and materialize ALL the streams to VM first. But there are those JCL sources 2 b read

Comment: My point is that using any stream is essentially trivial. So why ask about it. And why ask to do it to disk but not memory, and also to memory stream. My point is that the question is vague and unspecific.

Comment: Well, with typical win32 Delphi app you can only expect 1GB of heap memory warranted for your use. If you compress a LOT of data that taken TOGETHER might be over that then that is a reasonable worry. Still, that if a library an a FLOSS library at that. Do the test, read the source, etc. Smart Questions essay covers it. Or if what you really meant was "is there a better library for me to use?" - then see the SO FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR Jedi CodeLib today is a wrapper over 7-zip DLL API ( www.7-zip.org ) and thus is a bit overkill if you only need creating simplified old-school ZIPs ( such as Java JARs or Office OpenDocument or OpenXML files ).

Indeed, there is a difference, when the compression takes place - some libraries compress every particular file immediately when given data. And then committing the archive is only writing the end-directory of the zip. Some libraries though keep ALL the uncompressed content in memory and only compress it when committing.

Check ZeZippy*.pas files at https://github.com/Avemey/zexmlss/tree/master/zexmlss/src

This is implementing creation of ODS/XLSX zips with different engines. XE2 RTL and ZipMaster and Jedi CodeLib interfaces supported, you just can match their micro-implementations to see differences.

PS. AFAIR I also wanted to add Windows XP implementation, but seems got diverted from it :-)
https://github.com/the-Arioch/avemey.com/blob/master/zexmlss/src/zeZippyXP.txt

Comment: Never heard about this code. Can it also make zip files?

Comment: Creating zip files is THE ONLY thing those ZeZippy files can do. Quote: This is implementing creation of ODS/XLSX zips. However they were created to fit into a pre-existing library, that used to write temporary files onto the disk and then compress them from disk to the zip-file. So it is unifying that specific pre-existing workflow which easily might appear not suiting your specific needs. Consider it merely the reference point.

Comment: Not sure if I can use this library. I just installed it but this seems to be some totally different thing than a "compressing libary". Also this is very strange and I don't see any compressing function there http://avemey.com/zexmlss/delphizip.php?lang=en

Comment: Look, I didn't tell you to use the whole library. I suggested you to look at very small utility subset of it. Quote:  ZeZippy\*.\* . And i only suggested to you to READ those sources as a quick reference to several zip libraries. To read and learn and then choose which one to use.